# How to fetch only new changes from GIT Hub using JGIT

Tags: java, jgit

I written a below script to clone a repository, and It works fine. Also I'm using TestNG library to execute the script.

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void cloneGit() throws Exception 
    {
      String url = "https://${oauthtoken}@github.amazon.com/arrchanaMohan/xxxreports";
      String destination = ".//clone1//";

      CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(
                "${oauthtoken}", "");

      CloneCommand clone = Git.cloneRepository();
      clone.setURI(url);
      clone.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
      clone.setDirectory(Paths.get(destination).toFile());
      clone.call();
    }
```

I just want to clone the git repository once before It starts executing @Test method in a class, and It did. but Most of the time I encounter the below error message in output console.

```
  SKIPPED: insertRecords
  java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path "clone1" already exists and is not an empty directory
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:163)
```

To avoid this I just wanna perform "fetch" action. I already cloned the repo in my local If It exist then it needs to fetch only the updated records from the repo instead of again performing "clone" action.

Any leads?

Comment: Is that annotation? I'm using TestNG library to call annotations.

Comment: I would say the cleanest way is to: 1.) clone the repo, 2.) run your tests, 3.) delete the (local version) repo. This way you will always have the current version and can avoid trying to fetch the correct things. Also makes it easier to work with e.g. several repos. I would say that if you need resources for your tests it's a good thing to "clean up" after yourself afterwards to leave the system the way it was before you ran your tests.